# malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc Assertion failed

Tags: c

I keep getting this error:

> malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

This is the piece of code that causes the error:

```
BinaryTree * oldTree, * temp;
BinaryTree ** sorted;
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

oldTree = (BinaryTree*)malloc(cnt * sizeof(BinaryTree));
sorted = (BinaryTree**)malloc(cnt * sizeof(BinaryTree*));

/*
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
{
    oldTree[i].value = table[i].data;
    oldTree[i].freq = table[i].cnt;
    oldTree[i].left = NULL;
    oldTree[i].right = NULL;
    oldTree[i].parent = NULL;
    sorted[i] = &oldTree[i];
}

while (cnt >= 2)
{
    temp = (BinaryTree*)malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));

    temp->value = -1;
    temp->freq = sorted[0]->freq + sorted[1]->freq;
    temp->left = sorted[0];
    temp->right = sorted[1];
    temp->parent = NULL;
    sorted[0]->parent = temp;
    sorted[1]->parent = temp;

    for (j = 0; j < cnt - 2; j++)
        sorted[j] = sorted[j + 2];

    j = 0;
    while (temp->freq >= sorted[j]->freq && j < cnt - 2)
        j++;

    for (i = cnt - 1; i > j; i--)
        sorted[i] = sorted[i - 1];

    sorted[j] = temp;

    cnt--;
    k++;
}
createPattern(oldTree, table, cnt); 

free(oldTree); // May be wrong
free(temp);
free(sorted);
*/
```

Even comment out every bit of this code with the exception of the malloc lines themselves leads to this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: A quick look at similar questions - look  at the _Related_ side bar - suggests that there was a problem with dynamic memory allocation before the calls to `malloc` you show. If you can, run your program under `valgrind` to detect memory issues.

Comment: `free(temp)` malloced at inside of while-loop. It can not be directly released in this way.